# How to logically/relationally understand programming?

Tags: python-2.7

I have been learning how to code for about a month now, I understand a big part of the language concepts and terms but the thing is when ever i see a tutorial on how to make something and try to code it down or when i read someone else's code i relationally get lost I don't even seem to get the most basic thing like loops and so .
If anybody went through that ? What was the strategy that you used to relationally understand or to relationally write your own code ?

Comment: One word: Practice

Comment: The amount of time to understand coding is relative for different people, but a month is considerably a short amount of time for complex concepts to sink in and make sense. To think of it another way, understanding programming languages can be a lot like learning and understanding (or becoming "fluent" in) spoken and other written languages. Learning the first language is possibly the hardest, but learned early enough most don't recall the process and it came "naturally", but took years to become "fluent" by using it daily, reading/writing/talking, etc. Programming daily is similar to that.

Comment: thanks, that indeed is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something you grow into by doing. Keep studying -- more importantly, build something -- immerse yourself in your language and tools. Keep after it and the concepts will become more comfortable until one day they seem natural to you.